# Files in public folder on google drive not visible even via WebViewLink

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

So I've used a little Google Apps script to make a public folder (type: anyone, role: reader) and then I've requested and received the WebViewLink. But when I go to that link, it says there are no files. I've placed (via Google Drive web interface, not via the app script) an index.html file (document) in that folder.

Do I have to MAKE all the files in the folder via the app script?

I seem to have heard on one of the announcements about this that once the folder is created, you can just drop files into it.

Comment: This might be a bug, thanks for raising. I'll investigate it.

Answer (score 5):

Found the answer myself. The documents in the folder must be of the correct type or they just don't show up. E.g. a google docs document called index.html is NOT an html document. You have to create a standard html page locally and then upload it, but never open or edit it with google docs (drive, whatever) in order for it to be seen. I put detailed instructions on a web page hosted by Google Drive here:
https://googledrive.com/host/0B0ap0WDOII5mbjdwajNBMlRoZUU/

Comment: sounds like you may wantto report this as a bug?

Comment: hey that's great. but I can't see where we can view images like we view the html files. Like dropbox public files, can we not view anything else on google drive like images and not only hmtl files?